# sorting listview according to date from web service in android

Tags: android

I have a listview from web service with name & date as list item per line.i need to sort this listview according to date in android.How could i do that?

code i used:

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

....

```
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(Constants.REQUEST_ID,   webCall.parser.getValue(e, "name"));
            map.put(Constants.KEY_DATE, webCall.parser.getValue(e, "Date"));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,menuItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                Constants.REQUEST_ID, Constants.KEY_DATE

                                }, new int[] {
                                R.id.id, R.id.name});

                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting data from database ?

Comment: please see my code above

Answer (score 0):

1. retrive the list items from web service
2. sort the list with `util.Arrays.sort(myArray);`
3. display the list

Comment: You could have provided some reference or code. The three points that you have mentioned are the obvious.